# Split Brain Problem in Different Data Center (Logic, Failover)

Tags: elasticsearch, operating-system, distributed-computing, etcd, failovercluster

There is an issue that confuses me about **split brain calculation**.

- Case-1: I have 7 nodes in one cluster in two different zones. zone1 has 4 nodes, zone2 has 3 nodes, My current master node in zone2.. What happened if my network-isolated is outage?
- Case-2: I have 7 nodes in one cluster in two different zones. zone1 has 5 nodes, zone2 has 3 nodes, My current master node in zone2.. What happened if my network-isolated is outage?
- Case-3: I have 7 nodes in one cluster in two different zones. zone1 has 14 nodes, zone2 has 8 nodes, My current master node in zone2.. What happened if my network-isolated is outage?